# Q: tikz tree using mindmap library

Tags: tikz-trees, mindmaps

Is there an easy possibility to achieve a simple tikz tree using it's own mindmap library?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what exactly are you trying to achieve? An image (even a hand drawn image) or a link to an image showing the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you want to use mindmap to draw a tree? That is, the mindmap library draws mindmaps as trees but a 'simple tikz tree' is not a mindmap...